How important exactly is the Base Attack Bonus?
I am asking this because I have seen various different opinions of "what BAB you should get for your character" in different handbooks/guides.
Some say "just get at least +16 so you get your 4th attack".
Some say "if you don't have full BAB (+20) you are not hitting anything".
Some say "you can make a capable combatant as long as you have at least 3/4 BAB (+15)".
I think we all agree that 1/2 BAB is not enough for a combatant, but how many is enough? I have made a +17 BAB multiclassing character recently and found that she can hit AC 40 with a 70% hit rate (+33 AB in total, with magical items but without temporary buffs). It looks fine to me (even further lower to +15 would be "not bad" with 60% hit rate) in lv 20. Just wondering if someone can provide me some sort of "BAB standard" and explain the reason behind it.

I feel like I understand what you're going for here, but fear this question is largely going to lead you to answers that are heavily opinion-based. In the late/epic stages of the game where these kinds of numbers are relevant, it's important to remember that 3.5 comes before the time of bounded accuracy. As a result, your functional answer is almost entirely dependent on the DM/Campaign you're playing in, because Armor Classes can range from as low as the 20s to as high as 80+, and so can total attack bonuses.

@TheFallen0ne "It depends on your GM" honestly sounds like a pretty good answer to this question. Accordingly, I'm voting to keep this open.

@GMJoe while the question appears to be quite opinion-based at first, I think you're right here. This answer is basically a frame challenge, and it's a great way to answer the original problem. I'm voting to keep it open.

There is far too much variance to answer this question
The only things that are special about base attack bonus are iterative attacks, Power Attack, and requirements. The last iterative is at BAB +16, so anything higher than that does the trick there. Power Attack wants as much BAB as possible, but if you have +16 for the last iterative, you’re not missing out on that much compared to BAB +20. Still, it’s definitely the biggest thing you’re missing out on. As for requirements, there aren’t a lot of high-BAB requirements out there—a few prestige classes from Draconomicon and Epic Level Handbook (and the Draconomicon ones are dragon-only), and some epic feats (but perhaps not as many as you’d think), and Rapid Blitz (BAB +18, third attack on Spring Attack) from Player’s Handbook II are basically all there is.
Otherwise, all attack bonuses are equal. And attack bonuses are all over the place at high levels. Your relevant ability modifier can easily be anywhere from +13 to +30, and you might have major bonuses from elsewhere, or not. And especially if you’re talking about BAB +16 as a minimum, you’re looking at a difference of—at most—4 in base attack bonuses (BAB +16 vs. BAB +20 at ECL 20th—after that, you switch to epic attack bonuses and those always grow at ½ level). A difference of 4 in attack bonus when you’re talking about total attack bonuses that range from +35 to +100 is close to meaningless—but if you’re at the low end of that range, you probably want every point you can get.

By level 20 or epic content, your BAB is usually secondary to your AB modifiers in terms of what you can hit.
Because of that, I would say that depending on the game your DM is running, +16 for your fourth base attack is probably the most important figure.
When you get to things that have higher than 45 AC, if you're only factoring in your base attack bonus, you will never hit anything except on a nat 20, even factoring in a full +20 BAB and a +5 stat modifier from a 20.
To really crunch down on this, you need privileged information about the campaign; what is the highest AC monster you will ever face? Beyond that, you need to know what kind of magical weapons and items and spells will be in the game and readily available to you.
In an ideal world, against the hardest to hit monster in your game, a reliable auto-attacker wants to be hitting (at absolute WORST) on a 6 roll for their first attack; factor in haste, and that means for attacks 1-2 they hit on a 6, attack 3 they hit on an 11, attack 4 they hit on a 16, and for their last attack they need a nat 20 (21).
At the end of the day in this scenario, the +16 to give you those 4 initial attacks is more important than whether you have +16 or +20, because if the enemy has 60 AC your most important task is figuring out where to get at least another +30 to hit from various weapon, magical, circumstantial, and feat-based bonuses... or you're going to miss most of the time even if you have the extra +4 from the full +20.
This isn't to say that those extra 1-4 points of BAB are meaningless; you can use them to transform the above example, where your first hit then happens on a 2 instead of a 6, meaning your last attack could hit on a 17 instead of only on nat 20's.
But those 4 points of BAB have to be weighed against what bonuses you can get elsewhere by not earning them, always. If the trade-off nets you at least +1 to hit somehow for every BAB you lose in your build progression, then it's worth it.

I wonder how to get +30 bonus on attack roll when pre-epic. All I can think of so far are the weapon enhancement bonus (+5), attribute bonus (+11~+13), Greater Heroism (+4), Haste (+1), and Weapon Focuses (+2). That's maximum a total of +23~+25. Wondering if Mage's Transformation should be applied here to make it +27~+29.

@TerryWindwalker Divine Favor (+3 luck bonus with a potent enough potion), and Divine Power will increase your BAB to be equal to your character level, if you have enough UMD to wand it. So you're looking at 3+ (Level-BAB) in extra bonuses there. And that's just looking at cleric spells 4th level and lower.

Depends on your character build.
Some characters need base attack bonus more than others, even amongst combat builds.  In approximate order of least important to most important:
Natural attack builds
If your character relies on making a large number of natural attacks, like a Psychic Warrior using Claws of the Beast and Form of Doom, you probably don't care too much about it.  You won't get extra natural attacks for a high BAB, and once you pick up Multiattack you won't face very many attack penalties either.
Tripping
Trip-based builds rely on attacks of opportunity almost exclusively.  Thus, they don't really care about getting iterative attacks, and because tripping is a touch attack, they can also afford to have a pretty low to-hit.
Archery
Archery builds tend to be able to make a lot of attacks through feats and abilities, and in my experience they also don't tend to have too much trouble hitting targets.  It's mostly damage they're concerned with, and they don't have a meaningful way to convert BAB to damage.
Two-Weapon Fighting
A lot of the comments about archery apply here.  However, being closer to the fray  can make a touch of extra BAB handy for the odd grapple or sunder attempt from an enemy.
Charging
Two words: Power Attack.  The higher your BAB, the more damage you can pump into a charge and multiply with Leap Attack.  Plus, chargers are paradoxically the most likely characters to be making full attacks due to how important Pounce is.  A charging character can still function with a lower-than-ideal BAB, but every point missed should be strongly considered.
Grappling
Grapplers want every point of BAB available because BAB is used directly for calculating grapple rolls, and the inability to grapple with a magic sword means those rolls will have fewer outside modifiers.  Because of the nature of opposed checks, there is a far greater amount of randomness at play for these rolls as well, so it takes a massively higher bonus to gurantee a grapple check against an enemy than to gurantee an attack roll against an enemy.  So, if a grappler has to give up even a single point of BAB, it needs to be compensated with some greater bonus (most commonly by a size increase).

Fantastic point about Power Attack, can’t believe I forgot that. Still, if the difference between BAB +16 and BAB +20 isn’t that great, even with Favored Power Attack and Leap Attack (24 damage in the most generous interpretation). But trip is a Strength check, no BAB involved, and while grapple checks do involve BAB, they are also “like a melee attack roll,” which may (or may not) mean attack bonuses get added to it.

@KRyan I completely forgot tripping doesn't use BAB.  I'll ammend my post - I've clearly not touched a spiked chain in more time than I thought.

The largest factor in answering this question is what you are giving up to have the full +20 BAB.
The sheer variety of character builds and options that exists in 3.5 D&D means that a +20 BAB may well be a natural outcome of how you designed the character. While there are not many options that require greater than +16 BAB to take them, they do exist, and giving up those options should be taken into account when deciding if you need higher than +16 BAB.
That said, if you are considering altering your original character design for the singular purpose of having a +20 BAB by 20th level-or even just a +16 BAB-then whether or not it's worth it is dependent on what other options you are limiting yourself from taking.
As a very basic example; Druids, with their capacity through buff spells and wild shape, are more than capable of being attack-based combatants by later levels. Could you, as a Druid, multiclass into a full-BAB class for your last six levels to end up with a +16 BAB by level 20? Yes, you could.
To do this, you would need to give up:
A.) Access to 8th level spells
B.) Access to 9th level spells
C.) Huge sized animal forms
D.) All elemental forms
E.) Timeless Body (Possibly the least impactful, but still a loss)
Is it possible that the grand total +16 BAB-instead of +15 BAB you would have had you remained only taking Druid levels-is worth giving up these things? You get an additional attack per turn, if nothing else. However, you would be hard pressed to find anyone who considers that trade off worth those costs.
So, when deciding if a full +20 BAB is worth altering your entire character build, consider first and foremost what features and abilities that will cost your character. If the answer is, "Nothing, I'll just have a higher BAB," or "Some hit points and some skill points," then maybe consider the change.
If the answer is, "Access to 9th level spells," then you may want to reconsider that change.

Just as a heads-up, "Could you, as a Druid, multiclass into... for your last six levels..."  BAB on a 3/4 class is in increments of 4 levels. At level 16 druid you have +12/+7/+2, and would need four levels, not six, of a full BAB class to reach +16.

@TheFallen0ne I'm aware; The example was meant to be hyperbolic. Either combination will result in a +16 BAB by level 20. I chose the method I depicted to exclude even more options from the base druid class, to better emphasize the cost in comparison to just a +16 BAB. It was never intended as any form of recommendation on the 'best' way to get a +16 BAB as a druid.
